# Laravel 4 - get images of item in blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new in Laravel and stuck with a noob problem. I have 3 tables, users, items, item_images. When i post a item i save the images to item_images with the item_id and the other input data to the items table. now, how to get the first of x images for the item in my foreach loop?

This is my view

```
@foreach ($items as $item)

    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-image">  
            <img src="/uploads/{{ $item->image }}"/>
        </div>
        {{ $item->title }}

        {{ $item->type }}
        {{ $item->label }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This is the ItemImages Controller

```
<? class ItemImages extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array(
        'item_id',
        'image'
    );

    protected $table = 'item_images';

    public function item() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Item');
    }
```

}

The Item Controller

```
<? class Item extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array(
        'user_id',
        'type',
        'title',
        'label'
    );

    protected $table = 'items';

    public function item() {
        return $this->hasMany('ItemImages');
    }
```

}

And the home controller

```
<?php class HomeController extends BaseController {

public function home() {

    $items = Item::all();
    $images = ItemImages::all();
    $users = User::orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(2)->get();

    return View::make('home', array(

        'items' => $items,
        'users' => $users,
        'images' => $images
    ));

}
```

}

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try `$item->item->first()->id`

Comment: thank you. that helped in combination with correct relationships :)

Comment: The relationship looks correct. You should be querying only users or only items in the home method, depending on what you want to iterate.

Comment: i need both, want to show all items of all users in the main content and random users in the sidebar.

Comment: @BenSen, If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered.

Comment: @BenSen Ok, sidebars are best handled by view composers http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not defined relationships. I believe doing that will make the answer much simpler than the following:

```
<img src="/uploads/{{ 
    $images->filter(function($image) use( $item ) {
        return $image->item_id == $item->id;
    })->values()->image 
}}"/>
```

Comment: I had but i think they are wrong. i think i need to spend a few hours on relationships. thanks for your answer.